# How to request only one pipe per frame on USB Custom HID?

Tags: usb, hid, descriptor

In pipe and out pipe occur continuously within one frame when sending out pipe in Custom HID USB.

In pipe is requested periodically by the host pc every 1ms.

How can I modify the descriptor or FW that host pc don't ask for the in pipe within same frame when transfering out pipe?

Please let me know.

[USB Communication Capture Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Zwa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to modify the firmware or USB device descriptors to get that effect.  That is not a standard feature of USB.  You might try modifying the firmware of the device so that it can handle this situation (in fact I'm not sure why it would ever be a problem in the first place).  You could also maybe modify the drivers/software you are using to communicate with the device.

Comment: There was no particular problem.
However, I asked because my customer said that they used the competitor's product like that.